# SSO for the admin area

Tags: admin

So, given 2 magento sites, and soon to be 3, I would like to implement some kind of SSO between the admin areas of the given sites. AD/Kerberos integration would be sweet, but any other option would be great to have (separate SAML provider, OAuth, whatever works to have the guys have the same user pass between sites and not have them to separately login in every admin area).

I haven't found yet any extension to do that, and I'm not sure where to start (I'm not a dev, but I would like at least to know what to ask from the devs).

Answer (score 2):

Magento can be used as a OAuth server, but afaik only for the customer accounts.

But you can implement your own stuff. We hacked a few month ago a framework for this:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/LoginProviderFramework

You may have a look on it.

Comment: The repo looks to be dormant. Any alternatives?

Comment: Yes it is. No alternatives from my sdte

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt will your "loginProviderFramework" allow the admin user to auto login to external applications when they login to magento's admin panel?

Comment: @Nxlevel Our idea is to do it the other way around. So you are logged in, if something else is happening, like OAuth. What you want is not part of the idea - I don't think we can help you with this. But tbh I can't remember what we exactly did.

Answer (score 0):

For the admin area, if you want to provide SAML support you have 2 alternatives:

- https://github.com/pitbulk/magento-mod-onelogin
- https://github.com/opsway/magento-mod-onelogin

With the extension you will be able to deploy a Service Provider at Magento, and you will be able to connect it with any SAML Identity Provider (if you don't have any, you can use [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/)) that supports AD, Kerberos or Oauth as authentication sources.

This SAML extension for the admin panel is compatible with other SAML extension for the store, like http://cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/sixto-martin-saml-single-sign-on-magento-extension

Comment: Now you also have for SSO at the admin are:
http://cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/admin-saml-single-sign-on-magento-extension-sixto-martin